# "controller as" with isolate scope in directives not isolating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to learn to build custom directives in AngularJS.  Presently I am using AngularJS 1.5.8.

I am trying to create an example of a directive with an isolate scope where the controller scope is *not* visible, so that I can selectively expose things by adding them to 'scope: {}.'  In this example, what I *expect* to get is 'Name: Street:' because ctrl.customer should be unavailable to the directive.  Then later I would add "customer: '='" to "scope: {}" and I would get "Name:David Street:123 anywhere street".  Unfortunately, I am getting "Name:David Street:123 anywhere street" from this directive as it is written.

things I have tried:

- setting "bindToController: true"
- removing "scope: {}" and setting "bindToController: {}" (so I add "customer: '='" to that)
- setting "bindToController: false" (might as well, right?)
- repeatedly hitting shift-F5 after loading the html so make sure that I just don't have the old file cached.

testScope.js:

```
var app = angular.module('scopeModule',[]);

app.controller('Controller',[function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.customer = {
        name: 'David',
        street: '123 anywhere street'
    };
}]);

app.directive('sharedScope', function() {
            return{
                scope:{},
                template: 'Name:{{ctrl.customer.name}} Street:{{ctrl.customer.street}}',
                controller: 'Controller',
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                bindToController: true
            };
});
```

index2.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="scopeModule">
    <body>
        <shared-scope></shared-scope>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="testScope.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're mistaken. The point of an isolate scope is to make sure the directive scope is isolated from the outer scope, i.e. of the scope of the view using the directive. If a directive has its own controllerAs, and the controller exposes data, then of course the directive can access this data.

Comment: Or to say it a bit different for this directive the controller is its scope, so whatever you put in it will be accessible straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Controller` is the controller of `sharedScope` directive. It is a single entity. `this` in directive's controller is `ctrl` in directive's template, because both controller and template belong to a directive.

There's no reason to isolate directive's scope from itself.

Isolated scope is isolated from the scopes of other directives. [From the reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

> {...} (an object hash): A new "isolate" scope is created for the
>   directive's element. The 'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in
>   that it does not prototypically inherit from its parent scope. This is
>   useful when creating reusable components, which should not
>   accidentally read or modify data in the parent scope.

This means that if `sharedScope` directive has no controller and parent directive has `Controller` controller, this

```
  <div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <shared-scope></shared-scope>
  </div>
```

will result in

> Name: Street:

output.

Comment: OK.  That looks like what I want to use.  I am following a tutorial that uses $scope instead of 'Controller as' so I've been trying to convert all of the code over into the modern syntax as I follow the tutorial.

Comment: If I use that then how would I modify my directive to access that controller?
I tried 'scope:{customer:'='}' but didn't get anything, and 'scope:{ctrl.customer:'='} gave me an error.

Comment: When binding is provided as `scope:{customer:'='}`, it is expected that bound scope property will be passed as attribute from parent scope to isolated, like that `<div ng-controller="Controller as parentCtrl"><shared-scope customer="parentCtrl.customer"></shared-scope></div>`. It is supposed that `sharedScope` should have a different controller than `Controller` in this setup (an empty function for example).

Comment: That works perfectly.  When I comment out customer: '=' then the customer data drops out again.
I've noticed that I can pass in my customer object directly and skip the controller.
My ultimate goal is to ng-repeat through an array with objects of different categories and have different displays based on the object category.  Presumably I can do this with a directive that has a template that gives me a different display for each category of object using ng-show attached to an identifier.

Comment: `ng-switch` or `ng-if` will be possibly more efficient than `ng-show` in your case.